# projects_default.yml file in thorntail

Tags: thorntail

Thorntail generator does not generate any project_defaults.yml file in project structure. No resources folder also seen.Should we manually  place this file to configure project properties?
Note : I am new to thorntail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a file `project-defaults.yml` inside `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .One more query . I am integrating quartz with thorntail .How shall I store scheduler information so that it gets triggered when jar is up.In spring , we store it in application context.How to do this in thorntail.